# Updated to xcode 4.5 and now app build fails "Apple Mach-O Linker Error"

Tags: xcode, build, linker, mach-o

Hi I'm a newbie when it come to app development, but I DID have an app working just fine until I upgraded to xcode 4.5. The app has not changed but I am now getting 'Build Failed' when trying to put the same app on the same iPad I have always used.

The error I am receiving is show here http://i1342.photobucket.com/albums/o763/designedbyria/ScreenShot2012-09-27at162319_zpsfea02141.png (I stupidly am not able to include images) - Apple Mach-O Linker Error, does anyone know how I can solve this? I really don't have a clue what's going on and it's important I get this app working asap!

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance…

Answer (score 2):

If your app is for iPad only, just remove armv7s from valid architectures.  You can also do this for iPhone apps, and it will run on all viable targets, although it will be missing armv7s, which is the CPU for iPhone 5 - armv7 code will still run.

Alternatively, you can find an upgraded version of the Cordova framework built with armv7s support; you should just be able to build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Paul, this sounds like a good solution - the apps are going to be used in house only and only on iPads, could you please let me know how to remover armv7s for valid architectures? As I mentioned earlier I'm very new to this - apologies if this is a silly question.

Comment: Select the project in the left hand browser, then Build Settings/All.  You need to edit "Valid Architectures".

Comment: man alive, I thought that would work... I'm now recieving a completely different error "No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv6,armv6s armv7 armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=)."http://i1342.photobucket.com/albums/o763/designedbyria/ScreenShot2012-09-27at165112_zps566b80c2.png I think I may have done something wrong in architectures? It did say armv6 or something but now armv7... please help

Comment: You removed everything from valid architectures.  For iPad only use, all you need is armv7.

Comment: Thanks so much Paul, adding armv7 in architectures has fixed the problem and it now works :) your a lifesaver!

Comment: Paul, you are genius. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The error is on the line above. A framework you are linking (Cordova.framework) does not contain a binary for the appropriate processor architecture (armv7s).